# Why is $E\left(X_n X_{k}\right)-(E X_n)\left(E X_{k}\right)=\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_n,X_k \right)$ true?

Tags: statistics, covariance

Disclaimer: I don't know much about statistics

$X\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times n} $ or $ X:\{1, \ldots, N\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n} $ describe a measurement , where $N$ is the number of objects examined and each object has a data set $x_j=X(j) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $ j\in \{1, \ldots, N\}$ is assigned.
For $j\in \{1, \ldots, N\}, X_j \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ describes the $j-$th component of the measurement.
Why is the following true

$$E\left(X_n X_{k}\right)-(E X_n) \cdot \left(E X_{k}\right)=\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_n,X_k \right) \\ ?$$

I only know this formula of the covariance:
$\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y):=E((X-E X) \cdot(Y-E Y)) \in \mathbb{R} $, where
$(X-E X)$ and $ (Y-E Y)$ are the centered values of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Comment: What does $(X_nX_k)$ mean?

Comment: Sry, i meant $E(X_nX_k)$. its the dot product between two vectors

Comment: You don't need `\left` and `\right` on parentheses here. Those commands are for auto-adjusting the sizes of the parentheses (consider $(\dfrac 12)$ versus $\left(\dfrac 12\right)$, for instance), but in this case the standard sizes are entirely fine.

Comment: What happens if you develop the dot product in your known definition of the covariance ?

Comment: My first thought when I saw the question title was "isn't that just the definition of the covariance".  Sometimes it's defined that way; it's equivalent to the definition you learned.

Comment: The usual argument uses linearity of expectation as in $E((X-E (X)) \cdot(Y-E (Y))) $ $= E(X\cdot Y -X \cdot E (Y)-  E (X)\cdot Y+   E (X)\cdot E (Y))$ $= E(X\cdot Y) -E(X \cdot E (Y))- E( E (X)\cdot Y)+ E( E (X)\cdot E (Y))$  $= E(X\cdot Y) -E(X) \cdot E (Y)-  E (X)\cdot E(Y)+ E (X)\cdot E (Y)$  $= E(X\cdot Y) -E(X) \cdot E (Y)$

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply out the expression and consider $E(a*X+b)=a*E(X)+b$, here e.g. $E(X*E(Y))=E(Y)*E(X)$, taking $E(Y)$ as $a$